# Adding button with Text dynamically to UI at runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am working with `C#` an `Unity 5.6.1f1`, I done a mechanism that on UI button click should add an additional button with text to Panel that is already on UI, and it does work... since I am able to see Object appear there

[image]

```
public void MakeButton(string direction)
{

    GameObject button = new GameObject();
    button.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    button.AddComponent<Button>();

    var panel = GameObject.Find("CommandPanel");
    button.transform.position = panel.transform.position;
    button.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetParent(panel.transform);
    button.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge(RectTransform.Edge.Left,0,10);
    button.SetActive(true);
    button.layer = 5;

    //button.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[0].text = "New Super Cool Button Text";

}
```

problem is it isn't visible and reason for that I believe that there is no text there... now how do I know that...

I tried running the following `button.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[0].text = "New Super Cool Button Text";`

and it gave me

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   Hero.MakeButton (System.String direction) (at Assets/Scripts/Hero.cs:37)
>   Hero.Down () (at Assets/Scripts/Hero.cs:14)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:154)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:637)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:773)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:52)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:35)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:44)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

Also as you can see in the screenshot there is no triangle Under `New Game Object` like it is under `Run` which is also a button...

**How do I add from the script Button that has Text on it to panel in Unity?**

Comment: @Hellium answers is the right one but I'd simply add that you can create a button from code by replacing `GameObject button = new GameObject();` with `GameObject button = new GameObject("Button_Name", new Type[] { typeof(Image), typeof(Button) });`. Of course you need to create another object with a `Text` component and set it as child afterward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly advise you to [instantiate a prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html) instead of creating the button from scratch.

A gameobject with a RectTransform and button only won't be visible, and won't react to clicks, because you need additionnal components (such as Canvas Renderer and Image / Raw Image).

```
// Drag & Drop the prefab of the button you will instantiate
public GameObject buttonPrefab ;

public void MakeButton(string direction)
{
    // Instantiate (clone) the prefab    
    GameObject button = (GameObject) Instantiate( buttonPrefab ) ;

    var panel = GameObject.Find("CommandPanel");
    button.transform.position = panel.transform.position;
    button.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetParent(panel.transform);
    button.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge(RectTransform.Edge.Left,0,10);
    button.layer = 5;

}
```

Moreover, you have to be careful to one additional thing : when you ask Unity to create a button (Using GameObject > UI > Button), Unity creates several gameobjects (the button + child) with all the appropriates components (button, canvas renderer, text, ...).

Adding the Button component won't add all the other components and children Unity does. Thus `button.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[0].text = "New Super Cool Button Text";` won't work (since you haven't added the child and its Text component in your script)

Additional note : Check this link if you have some problems with placing your object : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html

Comment: Hi Hellium, thanks for the answer... I need to add multiple different buttons that would form a list based on person clicking UI.... and I have no ability to know how many times which buttons he will click...

Comment: And what is the problem? You are still able to customize the instantiated button by changing the components' values. If you need to place the buttons to create a list, take a look at the [AutoLayout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-UIAutoLayout.html) components you can add to your panel.

Comment: Just checking, lol... I am complete noob with Unity, heading to read on prefabs, thanks mate....

Comment: I've created a chat room if you need additional help : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/145955/unity3d

Comment: Hellium thanks so much... I managed this one on my own, but I really appreciate your willingness to help me...