# Multiple Saves in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity, and programming languages in general, so forgive my noobiness lol.

I am making a notepad, and I have been trying to figure out how to get multiple notes as well as the title of the note. I have a basic script for saving notes, which worked for one note, but I don't know how to save multiple notes. I even tested making 2 saves and wasn't able to.

Here's the script I had, full disclosure, I wrote half of it following a tutorial, the other half was my attempt at making multiple saves

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SaveControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

public string theText1;
    public string theName1;
    public string theText2;
    public string theName2;
    public GameObject ourNote;
    public GameObject namePlaceHolder;
    public GameObject placeHolder;
    public GameObject customName;
    [SerializeField]
    public int noteSave = 1;


    public void LoadButton1()
    {
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
            noteSave = 1;
            theText1 = PlayerPrefs.GetString("NoteContents1");
            theName1 = PlayerPrefs.GetString("theName1");
            placeHolder.GetComponent<InputField>().text = theText1;
            namePlaceHolder.GetComponent<InputField>().text = theName1;
            string customName = theName1;
        }
    }
    public void LoadButton2()
    {
        noteSave = 2;
        theText2 = PlayerPrefs.GetString("NoteContents2");
        theName2 = PlayerPrefs.GetString("theName2");
        placeHolder.GetComponent<InputField>().text = theText2;
        namePlaceHolder.GetComponent<InputField>().text = theName2;
        string customName = theName2;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }

    public void OkayButton()
    {
        if (noteSave == 1)
            {
            string key = "NoteContents" + noteNumber;
            Debug.Log("key is '" + key + "'");
            theText1 = ourNote.GetComponent<Text>().text;
            theName1 = customName.GetComponent<Text>().text;
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("NoteContents1", theText1);
            print(theName1);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
            }
        else if (noteSave == 2)
        {

            theText2 = ourNote.GetComponent<Text>().text;
            theName2 = customName.GetComponent<Text>().text;
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("NoteContents2", theText2);
            print(theName2);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Sorry it's super sloppy, I just started Unity like a week ago. I'm guessing the problem is partly that the noteSave variable isn't global so it just get's reset between scenes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the note name to get the note that way you can save multiple notes.

Here's an example

```
public void LoadButton() {
   // i assume this is your note's title/name
   string noteName = customName.GetComponent<Text>().text;
   string noteContent = PlayerPrefs.GetString("noteName");

   ourNote.GetComponent<Text>().text = noteContent
}

public void SaveButton() {
   string noteName = customName.GetComponent<Text>().text;
   string noteContent = ourNote.GetComponent<Text>().text;
   PlayerPrefs.SetString(noteName, noteContent);
   PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

As you can see in this case you need the note's name to be set to get the note's context.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you very much! I think I got most of it figured out, just a quick question, how would I make it create a button when there is a new save with said custom name?

Comment: That will make it a bit harder because now you have to save all the names of the saves and load them then use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386294/adding-button-with-text-dynamically-to-ui-at-runtime-in-unity to add the buttons

Comment: Well, I decided to leave such complicated things for a future project haha, but I have still been trying to get the multiple saves working, with multiple preset buttons, but it doesn't work. Here's my code currently, https://pastebin.com/32tKJmri
Sorry if I'm just being dumb lol, I even tried making it print the note name and the notecontents and it printed properly, but when I click the load button it's just blank.